# Finding tension in cables

Tags: kinematics

A 100 gram electric light is supported by two cables, one at an angle of 60°
with the ceiling, and the other being perpendicular to the wall. Assuming the
mass of each cable is negligible, calculate the tension in each cable.

[image]

I am not sure what to do here. I tried finding the force for both vertical and horizontal by using cos(90) and sin(60). Not sure what I do next. Please help. Thank you.

Comment: Would you mind describing in more detail what you tried?

Answer (score 1):

It's a question about vectors. Draw the force vectors and arrange them in a triangle (all the forces must cancel because the lightbulb doesn't accelerate off anywhere). You know one of the vectors (size of force and direction) and you know all the angles so you can work out the size of the force (i.e. length of side) for the other two.